# Text classification precision and recall

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, precision-recall

Basically I had to do an application for classifying documents based on the part of the speech of the vocabulary of the words. The algorithm that was used for learning the classification problem was ready made and handed over for me. 
Based on the examples I got, I need to interpret these results( precision, recall, accuracy). Can someone say his opinion if these results are good or not?

```
accuracy = 0.91 (true positive + true negative)/all
f-measure = 0.34
precision = 0.45
recall = 0.33
negative rate = 0.92
```

Comment: It really depends on the task.  f-measure of .34 and recall of .33 are in general not very impressive.  but of course, it could just be hard task.

Comment: Here, the F-measure gives more weight to recall than to precision. I guess beta is set to 2 (F2-score or F2-measure). You should interpret these results accordingly. That is, for this task recall is more important than precision...